# How can I change one string in multiple files in few subdirectories?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal, git-bash

My question is how can I change one word in many txt files in one directory and multiple subdirectories in BASH? I did as below (check all similar topics) but it is still not working. changePhrase is a name of directory where the subdirectories and files are. Inside that files there is a string that I want to change. I have to make it with a for loop (it's a task).
Where is my mistake? Thank you.

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in changePhrase; do
    if [[ -f $file ]] && [[ -w $file ]]; then
        sed -i -- 's/old/new/g' "$file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling this script?  Is changePhrase a list of all of the text files you want to change it in?

Comment: @Campbell changePhrase is a name of directory where the subdirectories and files are. Inside that files is a string that I want to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do

```
find changePhraseDir -type f -a -writeable|xargs sed -i 's/foo/bar/'
```

- `-type f` -> file
- `-a` -> and
- `-writable` -> your `-w`

Answer (score 0):

I think your code will work if you just add find to the for loop so:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in `find changePhrase`; do
    if [[ -f $file ]] && [[ -w $file ]]; then
        sed -i -- 's/old/new/g' "$file"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If changePhrase is the name of your directory try to append `/**{,/*}` to it. Using the globbing will make the loop go over all the files.

Comment: how? can you write it, please

Comment: `changePhrase/**{,/*}`