# Why this bash script is not running?

Tags: string, bash, shell, terminal

I have to make a script that will be changing one string with different word in the current directory and all subdirectories in this current directory. I want to replace name Leo with Leonidas in all files in directory and all files in subdirectories.

#### I have two questions:

1. Why this script is not changing string in files in *subdirectories*?
2. Why this script can be executed only once? When I try to run it for the second time, it's not working.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   for file in *; do
   if [[ -f $file ]] && [[ -w $file ]]; then
       sed -i -- 's/Leo/Leonidas/g' "$file"
   fi
   done
   ```

Comment: `*` will not expand directories, try substituting `*` with something like `$(find . -type f)`.

Comment: Same question asked yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53365081/how-can-i-change-one-string-in-multiple-files-in-few-subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

> Why this script is not changing string in files in subdirectories?

As mentioned in my comment, `*` does not expand subdirectories. You can use something like `find` to search subdirectories.

```
#!/bin/bash

targetdir="$1" # set this to the directory of files you want to change

for file in $(find "$targetdir" -type f); do
    if [[ -f $file ]] && [[ -w $file ]]; then
        sed -i -- 's/Leo/Leonidas/g' "$file"
    fi
done
```

> Why this script can be executed only once? When I try to run it for the second time, it's not working.

Because you are running it in the same directory as the files you are updating with `sed`. Hence, even your script will be updated by `sed` because it contains the word `Leo` in the line `sed -i -- 's/Leo...`. Your script must not be in the same directory with the files you are trying to update.

By the way, you can achieve the same effect without a script:

```
find . -type f -writable | xargs -i sed -i 's/Leo/Leonidas/g' {}
```